# When talking about a specific week (week 1, week 2, etc), is the correct preposition in?

Tags: prepositions

For example:

This happened in week 1. That happened in week 2. This will happen in week 4.

Would "on" be possible in any situation?

Thanks.

Comment: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+week%2C+on+the+week&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows that _in the week_ is very much more common than _on the week_.

Comment: @KateBunting: But nobody except non-native speakers would ever say *That happened in **the** week two*, so that chart doesn't match OP's context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preposition use is *very* flexible in English. The [most common preposition](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20week%20two%2Cat%20week%20two%2Cin%20week%20two&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) for OP's context is ***in***, but ***on*** and ***at*** are perfectly acceptable alternatives, and there are probably others that haven't occurred to me...

[image]

Offhand I can't think of any context where the choice of preposition makes any difference to the *meaning*. Sometimes different prepositions indicate different relationships between the two texts elements they connect. But the relationship between the primary assertion *(**this happened**)* and the adverbial element *(PREPOSITION "week" NUMBER)* is always the same here, so any preposition is semantically irrelevant.

Note that with *some* adverbial elements, such as *It happened **yesterday***, we don't use any preposition at all<sup>1</sup>. Imho this *strongly* implies that it doesn't matter much which preposition you use in related contexts.

---

<sup>1</sup> Following the model of *It will happen **tomorrow***, etc., in *some* (primarily, informal conversational) contexts, native speakers might omit the preposition completely *That happens week five*. It really isn't very important.

Comment: To my native speaker mind, *at week one* connotes some ongoing process that took place over multiple weeks, and had different effects at different times (i.e. "X happened at week one, Y happened at week two, etc."). You might also write *by week one* for the same meaning.

Comment: So how does ***at** week one/two/...* differ from ***on/in** week...* according to your way of thinking? I certainly don't see ***by** week N* as having the same meaning as ***in/on/at*** - those three all imply something happens *during* the specified week, whereas ***by*** means *before* (sometimes also *during*, but there's always uncertainty as to whether the usage is "inclusive" or not).

Comment: To my mind, **at** and **by** are synonymous in this usage, and **in/on** mean "during."

Comment: oic. As I said above, there's always uncertainty as to whether *You'll have my report **by** Monday* means the boss can expect to get the report first thing Monday morning. To some people (usually, hard-pressed workers with deadlines) ***by tomorrow*** can mean delivery at any time up to and including 1 minute to midnight tomorrow night. I *don't* see ***at*** and ***by*** as synonymous in such contexts anyway, but I'd be interested to know if in *I'll deliver the project progress report **by / at** week 4,* the choice of preposition makes any difference to you on that "inclusive" front.

Comment: In this usage, I see "week 4" as indicating some point within an ongoing process (as described in my answer), which is why I perceive **at** to be synonymous with **by** - you are describing the progress that has been made over the course of that four week period. As such, inclusion vs. exclusion is not particularly important - you are describing the (average) state of the process over the whole of week 4, with both prepositions. If there's no ongoing process, then you can't say "week 4" (in my dialect) in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps that wasn't a very good example - I wasn't really thinking about the span of time *covered* by the progress report, but I suppose I'd have assumed "weeks 1 to 3 inclusive". It wouldn't have occurred to me that week 4 might be included, because to me, ***by week 4*** implies *ideally, on Monday morning in week 4*. There wouldn't be any scope for such ambiguity if I'd been promising a *projected future sales report*. And to my mind, OP's *this happened then* context always implies *events occurring at "points" in time*, not *"processes" (that have "duration")*.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers have already handled the preposition, but I just wanted to point out something else that may cause problems: At least in the United States, and I imagine in at least a few other English-speaking countries, **we don't number our weeks relative to the year.** If you say "week 12," it is assumed that this is twelve weeks after some implied event, not twelve weeks after New Year's Day (as is [common in some cultures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Numbering)). Instead, we would say something like "the fourth week of March" (or the third or fifth, as appropriate). If that's ambiguous (for example, because March begins with a short week, or begins on a Saturday or Sunday), then we might instead say "the week of March 20" (which will be a Monday in 2023 - I would suggest avoiding Saturdays and Sundays because, while the US generally regards weeks to begin on Sunday and end on Saturday, this is not the case in other cultures and might cause confusion).

On the other hand, "week 12" is entirely reasonable if you're talking about something like pregnancy, where the implied starting point is conception, or any other ongoing process that takes multiple weeks to complete. You just can't use it to refer to weeks of the year.

Answer (score 3):

To specify points in time (as opposed to spans of time), generally speaking:

- "at" comes before time periods shorter than a day
- "on" comes before time periods of one or two days
- "in" comes before time periods longer than two days

**So "in" comes before "week".**

Common exceptions:

- times of day that begin with "the" (*at night*, but *in the morning*)
- "*at the weekend*" in some (most??all??) varieties of British English