# "on the week before" Vs. "in the week before" Vs. "the week before"

Tags: prepositions

Is it ever grammatical and idiomatic to say "in/on the week before" or should one simply say "the week before" and omit any prepositions?

For example: How should I say "you should submit this assignment sometime in the week before Christmas"? Should I simply say "You should submit this assignment the week before Christmas"?

Second example: "we traveled [in/on] the week before Christmas"

Comment: "In the week before Christmas" implies "at any time during that week" (i.e. it would be OK to submit it on Christmas Eve). If you mean "seven days before", you should say "**a** week before".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When talking about a specific week (week 1, week 2, etc), is the correct preposition in?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/328062/when-talking-about-a-specific-week-week-1-week-2-etc-is-the-correct-preposi)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it's a bit different. That question is about numbered weeks, right? For that question, I'd find "in" comfortable, but here, I'd personally find "the week before" more comfortable than "in the week before".

Comment: @starball: To me, ***the** week before Xmas* sounds weird regardless of whether it's ***in***. I don't know what "the" week before Xmas means. The seven (or *six*?) days before the 25th? The nearest whole week? Starting on which day of the week? So far as I'm concerned, only ***a** week before Xmas* makes sense, which is exactly ***one day*** (Dec 18). The assignment must be submitted ***on that day*** (neither later nor *earlier*) given OP's phrasing. Additional preconditions like ***no later than*** aren't conveyed by telepathy and wishful thinking - if you mean that, you gotta *say* it.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! @FumbleFingers I actually meant sometime in the week before Christmas, but admittedly the example wasn't great (in real life, if someone says something like this they want to target instead a specific day and hour for deadline). It'd more or less like "submit the finished project between the 1st and the last day of the week before xmas"; no sooner than the 1st day, no later than the last day. From your other answer, I think that in/on/at would be acceptable, with "in" being the most popular?

Comment: It looks like only "in the week before Christmas" is ever used, not really "on" or "at" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+week+before+christmas%2Con+the+week+before+christmas%2C+at+the+week+before+christmas&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3